# Why do I see so much C code that omits a return type for main? Why does it work?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I went to this [website](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php) that compiles C online and saw the `main` function declared without a return type.

I'm aware of some questions concerning this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c), but I didn't find any about omitting the return type. I tried to compile the code using gcc and it worked.

Does this mean that if we don't put a return type on `main`, it will assume it is int (or any other type)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCC default main return value is not zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936473/gcc-default-main-return-value-is-not-zero)

Comment: It is *very close*, but not an exact duplicate—at least not the way I read it. That question is talking about main functions that do not return a value (e.g. 0) like they are supposed to. This question is talking about main functions that are not declared with a return type. (Although I'd be surprised if this *isn't* a duplicate of *something*.)

Comment: Not duplicate, I know if you omit the RETURN STATEMENT it returns 0, I'm talking about OMITTING TYPE IN SIGNATURE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C89 standard, to preserve compatibility with the original K&R version of C that did not have function prototypes as we now know them, allowed functions to implicitly return `int`. Any function that was declared without an explicit return type (i.e., `void`, `float`, etc.) was assumed by the compiler to return `int`.

Thus, when the `main` function was declared without a return type, it was assumed to return type `int`. All was well and good, since `main` was *supposed* to return `int`, according to the standard.

However, this changed in C99. The default/implicit `int` rule was removed from the language specification. Functions without an explicit return type are no longer assumed to return `int`.

That means that for any modern compiler, adhering to the current version of the C language specification, a declaration of `main` without a return type is invalid.

As for why it works on GCC, this is because by default, GCC still adheres to the C89/C90 standard, unless you explicitly specify `-std=c99` as a compiler flag. And for why you still see this online, well, there are two reasons. The first is the one I've already given: it was legal in older versions of the language specification, and lots of old code hasn't been updated. The second reason is that, unfortunately, there is lots of *bad* C code online and in books. You may have just found some.

Comment: ... and it's also a good way to save a few bytes in a code golf competition.

Comment: Eek! Please don't get any ideas about writing code from reading code golf submissions. :-)

Comment: I was thinking about making some video tutorial in C so I decided to use an online compiler which would be more portable and then I saw this main without a return type for the first time (I was like 'wtf?')

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn on warnings, GCC should tell you that this is normally forbidden:

```
test.c:1:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
 main()
 ^
```

This used to have a defined meaning in older C, where the default type of functions was `int`. Compilers still support it in order not to break code and because it is not a big issue, i.e. the code isn't suddenly ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

If the return type is omitted in C89, the function is presumed to return a value of type `int`. In C99/11, it is not legal to omit the return type of a function. The signature of `main` is defined as:

**C11 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup:**

> 1 The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Compile your code with `-std=c99` flag and your compiler will raise a warning about the omitted return type.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on this -std=c99, I didn't know about it.. Some friends had trouble once because the professor wanted c99 and they didn't use the same compiler as the professor...