# Java's System.exit(0); vs C++ return 0;

Tags: java, c++, return, exit

When we learn C++ in school, our professor will tell us to write `return 0;` at the last line of codes in the main function and it is considered as a good programming practice.

In Java, I realise some people writes `System.exit(0);` at the last line of the main method.

However, in C++, if I use `exit(0);` I get penalized by my professor, because (in school) for procedural programming, we are expected to let the program flow till the end of main and let the program stop naturally.

**My question**: Is Java's `System.exit(0);` similar to C++'s `return 0;` ? (Or is it similar to C++'s `exit(0)`)

Is it bad practice to use `System.exit(0)` in java when it is unnecessary (I.e.: writing it in last line of main method)?

Comment: That's rather contextual, as an "old school" developer, I was taught that there was entry point and one exit point (talking about functions and methods), but this can be held true for `System.exit` as well. The problem with using this within your code is the same as having multiple `return` statements in your functions/methods, they are easy to miss and can make understanding the code more difficult.  Having said that, there are exceptions to every rule and some projects may require your terminate the running program midstream...but I would still be looking for away to avoid it...

Comment: I never used `System.exit(0);` at the last line of the main method.

Comment: @AnkitLamba And much like C++, one is silently added.

Comment: Maybe this question will help explain: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3715967/3651800

Comment: @MattCoubrough I just came from the link you pasted.

Comment: @user3437460 then you should've mentioned that in your question and stated that it didn't clarify things for you.

Comment: `System.exit(0);` in java equals `exit(0);` in C

`return;` or `return 0;` in java equals `return;` or `return 0;` in C.

exit closes the entire process while return just exits the subroutine or function.

Answer (score 19):

Java's `System.exit(0)` is like C++'s `exit(0)` in that

- It terminates the process
- It can be called from **anywhere** in the program.

The latter point makes it an “unstructured” control-flow construct that academic types tend to frown on.  (In this case, they've got a good reason: If a function reports a failure via an exception (or old-fashioned return code), it's possible for the caller to recover from the error, but `exit` burns that bridge.  Of course, sometimes errors do need to be treated as fatal.)

In C++, `return 0` is equivalent to `exit(0)` **if it's in the `main` function**.  (In other functions, it doesn't mean anything special.)

The relevant different between C++ and Java here is the return type of `main`.

- In C++, `main` must return `int`.  Normally, this would mean that it *must* have a `return` statement, but the C++ standard makes `main` a special case with an implied `return 0;` as the end if you don't write one.
- In Java, `main` must return `void`.

In C++, it's common to write `return` statements in `main`, even though it's technically redundant, for stylistic consistency with all the other non-`void` functions in your program.

In Java, you can't `return` the exit code from `main` because it's a `void` function.  So, if you want to explicitly specify an exit code, you have to use `System.exit`.

It's not *wrong* to end every Java `main` function with `System.exit(0)`, but it's just not idiomatic to do so unless you've got a construct like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
       //... do the work
       System.exit(0);
   } catch (Throwable t) {
       //... report the error
       System.exit(1);
   }
}
```

Comment: It **is** wrong to end the `main` method with an `exit` if your application uses non-daemon threads for longer than the main thread's lifetime.

Comment: @Darkhogg So what's the right way to set exit code in java? Join on all non-daemon threads first and then exit(1)?

Comment: Won't exit(0) mess with RAII? Files/sockets/etc. opened in main may not flush their output correctly.

Comment: @josefx: Java doesn't have RAII.  Files/sockets/etc. must be explicitly closed.  (Though, recent versions of the language have a `try`-with-resources construct, similar to C# `using`, that make this a little more convenient.)

Comment: @dan04 I think I was referencing the c++ exit(0) in main part. An exit(0) in main can prevent the destructors of static objects from running, which may result in unflushed files, sockets, etc. .

Answer (score 9):

In Java System.exit(0),System.exit(1),System.exit(-1) is used to know if the execution of the program went good or bad. `0` is used when execution went fine. `1, -1, whatever != 0` when some error occurred, you can use different values for different kind of errors.

You can also say it like this:

**0**  mean everything Okay

**1**  means something which I expecting to go wrong went wrong

**-1** means something which I didn't expect went wrong

The [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) says:

> The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status
>   code indicates abnormal termination.

---

> Is Java's System.exit(0); similar to C++'s return 0; ?

Yes they both are similar.

> Is it bad practice to use System.exit(0) in java when it is
>   unnecessary

I would not say it is a bad practice but yes you should be aware of when to use it and where to use it. You can use it to throw an error for a command line tool via a exit code instead of throwing an exception. `System.exit(0)` terminates the JVM so you should be very much sure where to use that.

An example for that:

```
try {  
    runTheWholeApplication();  
    System.exit(0);  // Signifying the normal end of your program
} catch (Throwable t) {  
    reportErrorSomehow(t);  
    System.exit(1);  // Signifying that there is an error
}
```

Comment: So I assume it acts similar to C++'s `exit(0)`. Then maybe we should avoid using it unless we are writing programs with threads..etc ?

Comment: @user3437460 Yes. It's the same thing.

Comment: On POSIX systems, the exit code is an 8-bit unsigned integer.  You *can* return -1, but it gets interpreted as 255 (due to two's complement).

Answer (score 4):

> When we learn C++ in school, our professor will tell us to write `return 0;` at the last line of codes in the main function and it is considered as a good programming practice.

That's debatable. Has he also told you that `return 0;` is implicit inside `main`? Personally, I never write the redundant `return 0;` inside `main`, and I almost never see it in other people's code either.

Comment: I do, because I learnt on C89 which can return nonzero from main if you don't specify: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936473/gcc-default-main-return-value-is-not-zero

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Java's `System.exit(0);` is a direct analogue because the prototypical Java `main` method is defined as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

So it literally cannot `return` an `int` (although it can simply `return;`). In C++ you could `exit(0);` which is also equivalent.

Comment: ...and what about `return;`

Comment: @AnkitLamba Edited. Yes. You can simply `return`.

Answer (score 3):

The original operating system Unix heavily relied on command line scripts using and combining many small programs. A return code of a program was used for the control flow. Return code 0 meaning everything okay, non-zero for errors.

So the **C** `int main(...)` is a direct mapping, and `return 0;` at the end appropiate. An exit there is like throwing an exception, bypassing any return. It also disables calling the main from another program.

In **Java** `public void main(...)` this was simplified, and 0 is implicit. `System.exit(0);` has the same bad assumption that no other program calls `main`. Though in general `void` mirrored the 99% usage, now `System.exit(...);` is inevitable for a non-zero error code.

This must also be seen as a more general design decision; C heavily relies on return codes of functions, which makes the control flow difficult or error prone, whereeas Java introduced the usage of Exceptions as possible obligatory control flow, with a freely chooseable catch. Nowadays an alternative to `System.exit(13)` might be `throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unlucky");`.

Comment: So in your opinion, is it bad practice to use `System.exit(0)` in last line of java main?

Comment: @user3437460:- No it is not a bad practice. I would explain a scenario like when you're writing a batch or shell script, every program the script runs has an error code on exit. Typically, if the error code is zero no action needs to be taken but if the error code is non-zero you may want to write a routine to deal with it, even if it only quits prematurely. So in this case it is not a bad idea to use System.exit()

Comment: Yes, superfluous and doing more work, like `x = x;` or `return;`. Mind, for a program that uses those return codes, it might be considered documentation: a hint.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks for reply, your solution is more in depth than the rest. `+ 1 from me`

Comment: @user3437460 you are right too; but a JVM program exit normally does return 0, so one does not need to write it explicitly; just like writing `return;` at the end of a void function is a sign of an uncertain programmer. But as said above, it could be styling, to list all `System.exit(...)`s.